# How to write stored procedure to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like to create a stored procedure that takes in a string of comma separated values like this "1,2,3,4", and break it apart and use those numbers to run a query on a different table.

so in the same stored procedure it would do something like

```
select somefield from sometable where somefield = 1
select somefield from sometable where somefield = 2
select somefield from sometable where somefield = 3
select somefield from sometable where somefield = 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you google this, there are so many of answers!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Erland Sommarskog's excellent article on the topic of how to pass a list of values to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005:

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

From that, you should be able to create your query based on the criteria you have.

Answer (score 3):

See here  http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV
assuming you want to do this

```
select somefield from sometable where somefield in(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice looking example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153409/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/031004-1.shtml).

With the split function defined in the link you can do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id in ( SELECT convert(int,Value) FROM dbo.Split(@list_string,',')
```

Alternatively you could use a table valued function version of split to join into your main query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get complex you can convert the input string into a temp table/table variable and then do a series of IF statements or queries at your leisure.

SQLServer proc to take a comma delimited input string and return it as a table variable.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'fn_parseString' AND (type = 'TF' OR type = 'IF' OR type = 'FN'))
     DROP FUNCTION fn_parseString
GO

/* This function takes a comma delimited string of information and parses it based on commas, returning the resultant strings.  */

CREATE FUNCTION fn_parseString
(@StringToParse TEXT)
RETURNS @StringTable TABLE (ParsedString VARCHAR(8000), StringIndex INT)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @CurrentString VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @CurrentStringIndex INT
DECLARE @TextLength INT
DECLARE @Index INT
DECLARE @Letter VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @PreviousLetter VARCHAR(1)

SET @CurrentString = ''
SET @CurrentStringIndex = 0
SET @TextLength = DATALENGTH(@StringToParse)
SET @PreviousLetter = ''

SET @Index = 1
WHILE @Index <= @TextLength
   BEGIN
    SET @Letter = SUBSTRING(@StringToParse, @Index, 1)

    IF @Letter = ','
       BEGIN
        SET @CurrentStringIndex = @CurrentStringIndex + 1

        INSERT INTO @StringTable
            (ParsedString,
             StringIndex)
        VALUES  (@CurrentString,
             @CurrentStringIndex)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
           BEGIN
            DELETE
            FROM    @StringTable

            RETURN
           END

        SET @CurrentString = ''
       END
    ELSE IF @PreviousLetter <> ',' OR (@PreviousLetter = ',' AND @Letter <> ' ')    /* Get rid of the spaces inserted when the string was created. */
       BEGIN
        SET @CurrentString = @CurrentString + @Letter
       END

    SET @PreviousLetter = @Letter

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
   END

IF @CurrentString <> ''
   BEGIN
    SET @CurrentStringIndex = @CurrentStringIndex + 1

    INSERT INTO @StringTable
        (ParsedString,
         StringIndex)
    VALUES  (@CurrentString,
         @CurrentStringIndex)

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
       BEGIN
        DELETE
        FROM    @StringTable

        RETURN
       END
   END

RETURN

END
```

Code to access the function elsewhere:

```
DECLARE @CommaDelimitedString VARCHAR(8000)
SET @CommaDelimitedString = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,cow,dog,horse'

DECLARE @StringTable TABLE
(StringValue VARCHAR(8000),
 ColumnID INT)

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO @StringTable
       (StringValue,
    ColumnID)
SELECT  ParsedString,
    StringIndex
FROM    dbo.fn_ParseString(@CommaDelimitedString)

IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    RAISERROR('An error occurred while parsing the AccountIDs out of the string.',16,1) 
   END


SELECT * FROM [Sometable] JOIN  @StringTable AS tmp ON [sometable.value] = tmp.StringValue
```